# generate blazor mudblazor table dynamicly

Tags: c#, html-table, blazor, mudblazor

i would like to build some dynamic table component based on 'MudTable' but so as i using reflection not need to define column list.

so i have DynamicTableComponent.razor

```
  @using System.Reflection
  @typeparam TModel

  <MudTable Items="@Model" SortLabel="Sort By">
  <HeaderContent>
    @foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(TModel).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy) )
    {         
    @CreateMudTh(p)
    }
</HeaderContent> 
<RowTemplate>
        
</RowTemplate>
<PagerContent>
    <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{50, 100}" />
</PagerContent>
</MudTable>

 @code
 {
  [Parameter] public IEnumerable<TModel>? Model { get; set; } 

  private RenderFragment? CreateMudTh(PropertyInfo p) => builder =>
  {    
      builder.OpenComponent(1, typeof(MudTh));   
      builder.AddContent(2, @p.Name);
      builder.CloseComponent();
  };
 }
```

so the usage would be

```
 <DynamicTableComponent 
   TModel="Customer"
   Model=customers >
  </DynamicTableComponent>

@code{

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    base.OnParametersSet();
    this.customers.Add(new Customer() { Id = 1, Name = "name1", OrdersCount = 1, DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now });
    this.customers.Add(new Customer() { Id = 2, Name = "name2", OrdersCount = 11, DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now });
    this.customers.Add(new Customer() { Id = 3, Name = "name3", OrdersCount = 13, DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now });
    this.customers.Add(new Customer() { Id = 4, Name = "name4", OrdersCount = 111, DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now });
}

class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int OrdersCount { get; set; }

}
}
```

and this AddContent does not work there is no error - it adds MudTh corectly bud does not add content (property name as header - there is in html only`<th></th>`). why?

and also if someone known than please point me a dirrection of how to achieve

```
 <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<TModel, object>(x=>x.Id)">Nr</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
```

using builder method? especiali this func part... probably using expression class??

if it is easier to use markups/bindings instead of this builder then im also open to it.

thanks and regards

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Also please give any error messages you encounter.

Comment: ok updated a bit :)

Comment: _why_ are you using reflection? Is it lazyness? Just type out all of the columns already! Making a 'generic' table is an antipattern IMHO. And you already see the problem when you want to add sorting...

Comment: im not saying that this is perfect solution but i will have many object lists to render some with 50+ properties so would be a lot faster to do this this way instead of typing it for every list type, also when adding some property to class will not cause me to add this column to every place - i would just add property and all tables will update itself

Comment: A class with 50 properties is not great design anyhow. Just think about a table with 50+ columns!! And if you go the reflection path, you would need reflection binding for the sort function... It will all impact performance. And the code can be quite difficult to maintain.

Comment: i known that - it is not my choice - this big clases already exists i just have to render them easly ;P

Answer (score 2):

This work for me and I also put the MudTableSortLabel into the header column

```
public RenderFragment CreateMudTh(Column c) => builder =>
{
    builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(MudTh));
    builder.AddAttribute(1, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((builder2) =>
    {
        builder2.OpenComponent(2, typeof(MudTableSortLabel<dynamic>));
        builder2.AddAttribute(3, "SortLabel", c.ColumnName);
        builder2.AddAttribute(4, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((builder3) =>
        {
            builder3.AddContent(5, c.Caption);
        }));
        builder2.CloseComponent();
    }));
    builder.CloseComponent();
};
```

Comment: can you please post whole working example? this indeed add sort label also but sorting does not work because lack of this lambda. or you have other solution and this works for you ? regards

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I would avoid components that are trying to do everything. It fails in long term run. Your code is working for me after small modification.

```
<MudTable Items="@Model" SortLabel="Sort By">
<HeaderContent>
    @foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(TModel).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
    {
        <MudTh>@p.Name</MudTh>
    }
</HeaderContent>
<RowTemplate>
    @foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(TModel).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
    {
        <MudTd>@p.GetValue(context)</MudTd>
    }
</RowTemplate>
<PagerContent>
    <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{50, 100}" />
</PagerContent>
```

Comment: yes this i known / tested - but wanted to known why does not work with add content cause this is the patch i need probably to do this MudTableSortLabel ? od to you known how to do this also as markup/binding?